# Text does not stay within background image on mobile

Tags: css

I have an H2 (id=cover) which I'd like to stay centered and higher up in a background image, but as the page size shrinks it eventually drops to the bottom of the image, then falls off of it on my mobile android phone. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Johnson Landscaping</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<div id="container">
<header>
    <h1>Johnson Landscaping</h1>
<nav>
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">contact us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</header>
<div>
    <div class="image">

        <img src="images/background-backlight-blur-color-262713.jpg" alt="" />

            <h2 id="cover"><span>Quality Garden Care on the North Shore</span></h2>

    </div>
<h2>Services</h2>
    <div class="Services">
        <h4>Garden Maintenance</h4>
        <img src="images/person-holding-a-green-plant-1072824.jpg" alt="person holding green 
plant">
            <p>Enter Details</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Services">
        <h4>Garden Design</h4>
        <img src="images/blade-of-grass-depth-of-field-environment-garden-580900.jpg" alt="blades of 
grass">
        <p>Enter Details</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Services">
        <h4>Tree and Shrub Pruning</h4>
        <img src="images/apple-tree-6035.jpg" alt="apple tree">
        <p>Enter Details</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Services">
        <h4>Pressure Washing</h4>
        <img src="images/photography-of-bricks-covered-with-moss-1089280.jpg" alt="bricks 
covered in moss">
        <p>Enter Details</p>
    </div>
</main>
</div>
<footer>
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

and css to go with it

```
html {
background: #f7f7f7;
color: #7cae49;
font-family: 'garamond', sans-serif;
}

body {
background: white;
margin: 0 auto;
font-family: 'garamond', sans-serif;
color: rgb(49, 46, 46);
text-align: center;
}

h1 {
float: none;
display: inline-block;
color: #5c7e3a;
width: 100%;
font-size: 50px;
text-align: center;
}

nav, li {
    display: inline-block;
}

header, footer {
    background: #DAF7A6;
    color: #7cae49;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 20px;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.image { 
    position: relative; 
    height: 60;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
 }

 #cover { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 200px; 
    width: 100%; 
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: flex, inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
 }

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;

}

a:hover {
    color: #0e69e9;
}

h2 {
    color: #7cae49;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.Services {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #7cae49;
}

img {
    max-height: 60%;
    max-width: 90%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;

}
```

Thanks for looking. Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to SO, Can you please create a a snippet of your working code as your tag are not closed properly in your given html

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
inside your style.css in #cover, change the top value to 0px;

```
#cover { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    width: 100%; 
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: flex, inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
 }
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks for your help. I don't know why but for some reason I was thinking the 200px in the top: was pushing it up instead of down :) that's what I get for copy and paste, I just didn't know how to put text into an image and that seemed like the easiest option when I googled it. Thanks again.